# how to get the a value of the resolution of an image in blender compositor?

Tags: compositing-nodes

I am creating a node group and this node group required the value of the X resolution of the image that the user will put so the user should put half the value of the X resolution but I want to make this automatic so the user should only put the image and half the value of X resolution will automatically generated,so how can I get the value of X resolution of the image that the user will put.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [driver](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Animation/Basics/Drivers) to easily get the render resolution from the scene, for a user selected image it gets tricky as you will need to know the name of the image or the image node to reference it's resolution.

I think you could achieve that with a [custom python node](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.67/Python_Nodes) but at this stage they don't integrate well, they don't update when a connected node changes so need manual updating which can lead to errors.